# How to pass String form BroadcastReceiver to activity?

Tags: android

i am new to android.

I am getting a string value from brodcast receivers

I want to pass the string value to an activity.

If any one know the solution ,Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as an extra value on the intent used to start the activity...

Comment: please give reaply clearly...

Answer (score 7):

From my answer to this question [Make my class take an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810943/make-my-class-take-an-argument/8811084#8811084):

You can pass parameters with an Intent by adding extra's to it, something like the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("paramName", "value");
startActivity(i);
```

In your activity you can use the getIntent() method to retrieve the Intent and extract your parameter(s) from it:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
String param = extras.getString("paramName", "default value");
```